# JavaScript - Swap colors

Tags: javascript, html, css

In this JavaScript example when user clicks on 'Change colors' button, it need to swap colors of two div elements. But it doesn't.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #first
        {
            border-radius: 100%;
            background-color: red;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        #second
        {
            border-radius: 100%;
            background-color: green;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="color">Change colors</button>
    <br />

    <div id="first">Random text.</div>
    <div id="second">Random text.</div>
    <div id="third"></div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('color').onclick = function () {
            var divColor = document.getElementById('first').style.backgroundColor;
            document.getElementById('first').style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('second').style.backgroundColor.toString();
            document.getElementById('second').style.backgroundColor = divColor.toString();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

But when I change it a little bit and remove 'background-color' from `<style>` and put it within `<div>` then it's working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <style>
        #first
        {
            border-radius: 100%;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        #second
        {
            border-radius: 100%;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <button id="color">Change colors</button>
    <br />

    <div id="first" style="background-color: red;">Random text.</div>
    <div id="second" style="background-color: green;">Random text.</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        document.getElementById('color').onclick = function () {
            var divColor = document.getElementById('first').style.backgroundColor;
            document.getElementById('first').style.backgroundColor = document.getElementById('second').style.backgroundColor.toString();
            document.getElementById('second').style.backgroundColor = divColor.toString();
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

So is there any way to make it works for solution when 'background-color' is within `<style>` in `<head>`?

Comment: it's illegal to ask question of this sort here (why your specific code doesn't work)

Comment: I would encourage to you sit and think hard, even if it will take a week, but it's imperative you solve such simple things yourself and not ask others to solve them for you. a programmer must first deal with the very basics before asking help

Comment: @vsync Well it's working, but I need to know for any example, if there is a way to make it work for 'background-color' in <style>, I need that kind of information, nothing more.

Comment: it's because, as the name suggests, `.style` only read style attribute of the element, and not it's CSS value, which is what you're after. you will have to google "how to get css value" or something like that

Comment: @vsync second example is what I come up first with, it's working just the way it need to :)

Comment: @vsync I disagree. The problem is clearly stated, and demonstrated by the two examples given. It seems quite clear to me. Although there's probably duplicates out there...

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol - I said the problem is clear. didn't say it wasn't, it's even ridiculously clear, as I said in comment #4

Comment: @vsync Could you maybe not be ridiculously condescending? "illegal", really?

Comment: @NickTirrell - I cannot not be. it is my nature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Element.style` only applies to styles within the `style` attribute of the element. If you want the computed style, which factors in stylesheets and the like...

```
var firstElem = document.getElementById('first'),
    secondElem = document.getElementById('second'),
    firstBackground = window.getComputedStyle(firstElement).backgroundColor,
    secondBackground = window.getComputedStyle(secondElement).backgroundColor;
firstElem.style.backgroundColor = secondBackground;
secondElem.style.backgroundColor = firstBackground;
```

This should swap the two colours, regardless of where they are defined.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me. I suspected that Element.style only applies to styles within the style attribute of the element, but wasn't quite sure. Again thank you.

Answer (score 0):

For this case it whould be more common to use 3 classes in css. One for defining the common style of the divs. And two for defining the differences. Switching the appearance in that case whould just require switching of classes. Such a set-up is far more flexible also for example in combination with annimations.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I had that idea, but didn't use it because there is to much things in this code. This is just a little bit of it, that I wasn't really sure about.

Answer (score 0):

A way to alter style using Javascript, without inline styling:

https://jsfiddle.net/6tyw211s/10/

```
<html>
<style>
#first
        {
            border-radius: 100%;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
        }

        #second
        {
            border-radius: 100%;
            width: 200px;
            height: 200px;
            text-align: center;
            line-height: 200px;
            float: left;
            margin: 5px;
        }

   .color{
     background-color: red;
     }
   .color1{
     background-color: green;
     }
</style>
<body>
    <input type="button" id="color" value="Change colors" />
     <br />
       <div id="first">Random text.</div>
      <div id="second">Random text.</div>
     <div id="third"></div>
</body>
<script>
    var y= document.getElementById('color');
    var f=document.getElementById('first');
    var s=document.getElementById('second');
       y.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if (f.className === "color1") {
        f.className = "color";
    } 
     else {
        f.className = "color1";
    }
    if(s.className==="color"){
     s.className="color1";
    } 
     else{
     s.className="color";
    }
  })
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -3):

You can use switchClass() in jqueryui to do it.
That way, you don't have to specify the background-color values to the divs.

```
  $("#color").click(function myFunction() {
  $(".first").switchClass("first", "second", 200, "easeInOutQuad");
  $(".second").switchClass("second", "first", 200, "easeInOutQuad");
});
```

[Here](http://codepen.io/carlos27/pen/kkbdjG) is a working version with jqueryui

http://api.jqueryui.com/switchclass/

Comment: the question is not tagged jQuery, nor jQuery-UI, this would require the use of two rather bloated libraries.